# Receive data from SharePoint 2013 Excel-workbook using VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have 2 questions.

1) Which SP Access/Rights do I need to be able to make this work?

I have looked at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29021/import-sharepoint-list-into-excel-using-vba-only but I am still unable to find my GUIDs (LISTNAME/VIEWNAME). I guess I might be missing SP Rights?

2) Is it possible first to run some `IF-statements` that will match data from the SP Excel workbook with data in my desktop Excel workbook? This would be a sort of security check, to make sure that data only will be transfered if these statements are answered correct.

Any help will truely be appreciated as I have no experience with VBA links to SP.

Answer (score 0):

I can only give you a partial answer.  The GUIDs come from the 'Modify View' URL in SharePoint.  Say you go to a given list and view that you like, then you select the menu to modify that view.  Once on that page, you take that entire URL and deobfuscate it either manually or using a web based solution.  That should leave you with a GUID next to the list and view sections.

[Picture of Menu - from walkthrough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXhG5.jpg)

As for permissions, I suspect you need contribute permissions to the list to get the GUIDs.  I'm not sure if there is another way to find the URL with the list and view GUIDs visible without going to that page. (I would suspect, but am not certain, that you need only read permissions to actually pull the report in Excel.)

> To create a personal view, you must have the contribute permission level for the list or library, such as by being member of the default site name Member group. To create a public view, you must have the design permission level for the list or library, such as by being member of the default Designer SharePoint group for the site.

-from Office Support site "[Create, modify, or delete a view](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-modify-or-delete-a-view-10c68afb-d901-4b15-848b-82d399eba089)"